# Regex - How do I find a word at the beginning, middle or end of a text and specify 20 letters before it and then 20 characters

Tags: regex

I am using this :

```
(\s*([a-z]\w+)){0,20}(class)(\s*([a-z]\w+)){0,20}
```

To find 'class' in this text 'example text':

`class` Doesn't matter whether he's creating an object, but rather whether he's in an instance `class method`. He's not, so self, if it's valid at all, is pointing at the  object, not an instance of the `class` Doesn't matter whether he's creating an object, but rather whether he's in an instance method. He's not, so self, if it's valid at all, is pointing at the `class object`, not an instance of the Doesn't matter whether `class he`'s creating an object, but rather whether he's in an instance method. He's not, so self, if it's valid at all, is pointing at the `class object`, not an instance of the `class`

I want to select 'class' and 20 characters before and after if they exist

Comment: I am not sure to understand... You want to find a specific word in a text, but not within the first 20 characters or the last 20 characters ?

Comment: I want to select 'class' and 20 before 'class' and 20 after 'class'

Comment: Start with something like https://regex101.com/r/yizzNn/1. Your example sounds rather unclear, sorry.

Comment: You may use: `.{0,20}\bclass\b.{0,20}`

Comment: It's working, thanks all

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The example you provided has an overlapping match where the text ends - match #7 only has 17 characters, as the previous match already captures the remaining 3 characters. Is it possible to make overlapping here somehow? You can look at my attempt to do this [here](https://regex101.com/r/1XmZu4/1) - the last `class` matches, but not the exact 20 characters before it.

Comment: I used this: .{0,20}?\b(class)\b.{0,20} and it's work good

Comment: So, it was my solution, I will post it with explanations.

Comment: It doesn't need `?` after `.{0,20}`

Comment: @anubhava It does because otherwise a `class` can be "eaten" be the greedily quantified `.{0,20}`.

Comment: Yes `.{0,20}` is greedy but also has `0`, that's why `class` won't be eaten by starting `.{0,20}` as you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/QWj2YB/1

Comment: @anubhava I mean the first `.{0,20}` grabs all instances of `class` there are. [Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/sSTjlK/1) finds `class Doesn't class matter whether`  while [mine will fetch `class Doesn't class matte`](https://regex101.com/r/sSTjlK/2) (so, the first `.{0,20}?` stops at the first `class`). Besides, with my approach, it is easier to build a regex to get overlapping matches.

Comment: @Asunez: I think your approach cna be fixed the way I described at the bottom of my answer. See https://regex101.com/r/1XmZu4/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
.{0,20}?\bclass\b.{0,20}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yizzNn/1)

**Details**

- `.{0,20}?` - any 0 to 20 chars other than line break chars, as *few* as possible
- `\bclass\b` - a whole word `class`
- `.{0,20}` - any 0 to 20 chars other than line break chars, as *many* as possible

And here is a variation in case you want to get overlapping matches (so that the 0 to 20 chars after `class` could also be searched for `class`):

```
.{0,20}?\bclass\b(?=(.{0,20}))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lwicAp/1).

You just need to get the match value and concatenate it with Group 1 value (the part of the text matched and captured with the `(.{0,20})` capturing group inside the positive lookahead `(?=(.{0,20}))`. Since the positive lookahead does not move the regex index, the next match will be able to start right after the whole word `class`.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584883/regex-how-do-i-find-a-word-at-the-beginning-middle-or-end-of-a-text-and-speci/45585303?noredirect=1#comment78129827_45584883). In short, the matches will be different otherwise.

Comment: It's easier to understand with capture groups highlighting. Thanks!